# Javascript Regular Expression: Mix of matching and non-matching in the same pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I had been working with a few regular expressions and I ran into a problem.

I need to run a replace on the following pattern:

The string must have a \E\ but it must not be preceded by \.br or a \R

Sample text:

```
Random\E\Text  - should match

\E\Text        - should match

\R\E\.br\      - should not match

\.br\E\R\      - should not match
```

Could anyone suggest a pattern that would be able to accomplish this?

I tried only for the \.br case and while

```
/[^\b\\\.br\b]\E\/g
```

fails terribly with good reason, the following pattern seemed to not work either:

```
/(?!\\\.br)\E\/g
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What if it's succeeded by a `\.br` or `\R`?

Comment: If its JavaScript, how about `str.indexOf('\\E\\') != -1 && str.indexOf('\\.br\\E\\') == -1  && str.indexOf('\\R\\E\\') == -1`?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Succeeded is ideally alright because not preceded would mean that at least the first '\' correctly belongs to the E so the succeeded one ideally should too.

Comment: @acdcjunior: That does definitely seem like the most ideal suggestion but I just wanted to know whether or not a regex will support what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not support lookbehinds, only lookaheads.  However, all is not lost!  You can a function for replacement:

```
input.replace( /(...|..|.|$)\\E\\/, function( match, prefix ) {
    if( prefix==='\.br' || prefix.match( /\\R$/ ) )
        return match;  // return match unaffected
    else
        return prefix + '<\\E\\ replacement>';
});
```

I generally find that a lot of regex problems can be solved by this kind of approach: instead of doing everything in one giant regex, break it up into manageable chunks, and do multiple regexes.

What's happening here is that the alternation operator is being used to look for the following patterns (in order):

```
...\\E\\        (catch potential instance of \.br\E\)
..\\E\\         (catch potential instance of \R\E\)
.\\E\\          (catch \E\ if it's at index 1 in the string)
$\\E\\          (catch \E\ if it's at index 0 in the string)
```

Once you've caught all of those possibilities, you can just examine what it was that was picked up before the `\E\`.  If it's `\.br` or `\R`, you just return the whole match (including the characters before).  If it's anything else, you can return the prefix followed by a replacement for `\E\`.

I hope this explanation makes sense!

Comment: I did follow the explanation. Definitely seems like a nice workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try `(\\.br|\\R)\\E(\\.br|\\R)`

Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds, but you should be able to negatively assert a match (if !match, string is valid).

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/hL3wN5

```
var str = "Random\\E\\Text";
if (!(/(\\.br|\\R)\\E(\\.br|\\R)/g).test(str))
    //do stuff because it doesn't test true
```

Comment: Aha, I see. That does make sense. Thanks, I'll give it a try and get back with the results

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
 # /^(?=.*\\E\\)(?!.*\\\.br\\E\\)(?!.*\\R\\E\\).+$/

 ^ 
 (?= .*  \\E\\ )
 (?! .*  \\\.br\\E\\ )
 (?! .*  \\R\\E\\ )
 .+                   // can be excluded if just a test
 $                    // can be excluded if just a test
```

*Edit* if that test matches, run the global replacement for `/\\E\\/g` its simple and fast.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. Thanks for trying though.